# Why can't I set AnchorPane's resizable attribute?

Tags: javafx

I created a FXML file using JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1. An AnchorPane is created by default. Why can't I modify the resizable attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why you can't edit bounds**

Checkout the javadoc on [layoutBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutBoundsProperty%28%29) and [boundsInLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty%28%29).  You will notice that both are [ReadOnlyObjectProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyObjectProperty.html), which is why you can't directly modify them in SceneBuilder.

**How to resize a node in SceneBuilder**

You can indirectly effect the bounds properties and directly set the resizable properties of the node by altering the min, pref and max height and width.

[image: SIZING]

You can also set the pref size by selecting the pane to be resized and dragging the resizing anchors the surround the selected pane.

**Further Information**

You might want to read the [Oracle tutorial on Tips for Sizing Nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm) and [Amy Fowler's presentation on JavaFX layout](http://www.parleys.com/share.html#play/514892290364bc17fc56c3bd).

Comment: I think Scene Builder could do a better job in indicating that it's a read-only property and cannot be set otherwise. Maybe they should just conceal the field, or put a hint bubble on there saying "This can only be modified via code, not here."  Or better yet, allow the designer to uncheck the box and place the `stage.setResizable(false);` in the `start()` method.

Answer (score 17):

Do you want to disable window resizing? If so, you can do that in your application program:

```
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change resizeble using code

primaryStage.setResizable(false);