# How to change 'Resizable' properties in Java FXML via SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, resizable

I want to disable the 'Resizable' Properties in my AnchorPane in SceneBuilder in FXML but the button is disabled.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I set AnchorPane's resizable attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934183/why-cant-i-set-anchorpanes-resizable-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is applying it on the Stage, not on the Pane.
You can simply disable it using `primaryStage.setResizable(false);`